# Play vs play on?

Tags: грамматика

The Russian for "I play guitar" is "Я играю на гитаре". However, this more directly translates to "I play on guitar", and if I use translation tools to translate "Я играю гитаре", that also becomes, "I play guitar" even though "I play on guitar" is a common expression as well in English.

So how common is it in Russian to drop the на? Do Russians always use the form "I play **on** an instrument" or do they ever use the shorthand expression?

Comment: "I play on guitar" is a common expression in English? Can you please link to some examples of its usage? Thank you!

Comment: Machine translation tools obviously have no validity checking (they're not like programming language compilers) so they will fix whatever broken input you provide. You can mostly trust their output but they will not validate your input for you.

Comment: @Quassnoi "Play on guitar" is far less common than "play guitar". However, you can use "on" by itself, for example: "Aside from Lennon on rhythm guitar and vocals, the track also includes Klaus Voormann on bass, Alan White on drums".

Comment: @ghostarbeiter: "playing _something_ on guitar" I of course heard a lot of times, as well as "on guitar" without "play". But both "play on guitar" and "play guitar", with "guitar" being the direct object of "play", sound way off to me, and I don't think I've ever heard or read either. Hence the ask.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Both "play guitar" and "play the guitar" sound natural to me, as a native speaker. Meanwhile "play on guitar" sounds a bit unnatural, but I can't really definitely say that it's wrong. But if you reject all of these, then how would you say играть на гитаре in English?

Comment: @ghostarbeiter: I would say "play the guitar".

Comment: *I play on guitar* sounds like Borat. It isn't common in the least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So how common is it in Russian to drop the на?

It's not. We always say играть на гитаре, as well as with any other musical instrument.

Я играю на баяне. Он играет на флейте. Девочка играет на пианино. Мальчик играет на трубе.
Even играть на нервах.

You can't expect all languages to follow the same structure.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

> Do Russians always use the form "I play on an instrument"

Yes.

---

Here's what you do in Russian to convey the concept of "extracting hopefully pleasant sounds from a musical instrument":

- Use the verb *играть* in an appropriate form.
- Take the noun or the noun phrase describing the instrument and put it in the **prepositional** case.
- Prepend the noun with the preposition *на*.

An example of this would be *играть на гитаре*.

---

And here's what you do to convey the concept of "to participate in an emotionally satisfying structured activity that yields no tangible product":

- Use the verb *играть*.
- Take the noun or the noun phrase describing the activity and put it in the **accusative** case.
- Prepend the noun with the preposition *в*.

An example of this would be *играть в футбол*.

---

And here's what you do to convey the concept of "to impersonate someone on the stage":

- Use the verb *играть*.
- Take the noun or the noun phrase describing the persona and put it in the **accusative** case.
- Don't use any prepositions

An example of this would be *играть Анну Каренину*.

---

Note that all these concepts are different. If you think about it, there's little connection between extracting music from an apparatus, having fun following the rules of a game and pretending to be someone else on stage.

It just so happens that you use the same verb in Russian (and in English) to describe all three, but in Italian, for instance, these would be three different verbs: *giocare, suonare, recitare*. They're etymologically related to English verbs "to jest", "to sound", and "to recite". The English words "jest" and "play" once both shared the meaning "to engage".

In Italian, you "play to" football, you "sound" the piano, and you "recite" Hamlet. It would be a big mistake to mix these words up.

In English, you "play" all three of these things: you play football on the field, you play the piano in the music room, and you play Hamlet on stage.

Russian is somewhere in between: it does use the same verb for all three, but with different governments. The government, or, in other words, what preposition and what case you use for the object, is what differentiates the meanings.

Saying something like ***играть в гитару** or ***играть на Гамлете** would be as big an error as using a wrong verb in Italian.

If you go to Wiktionary and open the [translations section](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/play#Translations) for the word "play", you'll find that this word is used in English to convey at least ten different concepts which are only tangentially related.

In most other world languages, these concepts are conveyed by different verbs or different governments of the same verb.

In most cases, you can't mechanically translate phrase structures between languages and hope they'll work the same way. Sometimes they do, but those would be either calques or happy coincidences. The default answer to "why doesn't this structure work in language A the same way as in language B" would be "because it's not supposed to".

Answer (score 1):

> ... if I use translation tools to translate "Я играю гитаре", that also becomes, "I play guitar"

If that's the case, it just means that you shouldn't trust these translation tools. "Я играю гитаре" means "I'm playing for the guitar" or "I'm playing towards the guitar" (I'm playing some kind of musical instrument and I'm only doing it so that a creature identified as the guitar  can hear me).

Comment: ...creature *identified* as a guiltar, otherwise it would be `Я играю Гитаре`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the translation tool unless its *output* is grammatically incorrect. If the *input* is flawed but still comprehensible, the tool is just doing its job by providing a sensible translation. Non-native speakers make errors because they don't know the language well; native speakers make errors because they write quickly and carelessly and don't proofread before posting. We still want a meaningful translation if the message is important (for instance, emails to customer support).

Answer (score 1):

You gave a grammatically incorrect but still comprehensible sentence to a translation tool, and it gave you a meaningful result. That's OK. It's *supposed* to do that, if it can. And modern LLM-based tools can. They're very adept at deciphering input that is written poorly or carelessly.

But just because the tool made sense of your incorrect input, you should not conclude that it was somehow correct after all. It wasn't. The Russian sentence needs the на.

Comment: That's the whole point. The logic of an electronic translator: "A person cannot  write such a ridiculous grammatical construction. He probably just missed some letters or even prepositions in a hurry. Therefore, I will translate as if these prepositions are still present in the phrase." User logic: "You see, I wrote a phrase without a preposition, and the electronic translator reacted to it as usual.  Hey, russian textbook authors, why are you forcing me to speak according to the rules of Russian grammar, if an electronic translator has just shown me other?"