В + sport (preposition)
For instruments, usually it's играть на sth. However, why does it become играть в once we start talking about sports? Why do we say  я играю в футбол with the в? Is that a specific rule?
Большое спасибо.

See also https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/27216/134

I think you need to accept idiom as it is in a language you're learning, without quibbling with it. Once you have established that it is на+Prep with instruments and в+Acc with sports, you are good to go. What genuine question can be raised about this?
